# Monte Carlo integration and mixture distribution

Tags: monte-carlo, mixture-distribution

How could I estimate an integral using Monte Carlo method when I have a mixture distribution? For example I want to estimate the below integral:

$I=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$

And my distribution is:

$p(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda_kp_k(x)$

And $\langle I^N\rangle= \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{f(x_i)}{p(x_i)}$ is a Monte Carlo estimate of $I$.

Is $p(x_i)$ the mixture density or conditional density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both solutions work in the sense that, if $Z$ denotes the index of the component of the mixture used to produce $X$, there is equality between the expected weights:
$$\mathbb E^X\left[\dfrac{f(X)}{p(X)}\right] = \mathbb E^{X|Z}\left[\dfrac{f(X)}{p(X|Z)}\right] = I$$

Here is a quick illustration of the fact:

```
#target function
f <- function(x) sin(3*x)
#mixture
p <- function(x) .3*dbeta(x,1,2)+.7*dbeta(x,2,4)
#complete sample
N=1e6
z=sample(0:1,N,replace = TRUE,prob = c(3,7))
y=rbeta(N,shape1 = 1+z,shape2 = 2+2*z)
w1=f(y)
w2=w1/p(y)
w1=w1/dbeta(y,shape1 = 1+z,shape2 = 2+2*z)
#estimators
est1=cumsum(w1)/(1:N)
est2=cumsum(w2)/(1:N)
```

with both estimators having similar behaviour in that simple example (blue for the unconditional version and orange for the conditional version):

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
#plots
plot(log(1:N),est1,ty="l",ylim=c(.3,.8),col="midnightblue",xlab="log(n)",ylab="")
lines(log(1:N),est2,col="orange2",lty=2)
abline(h=integrate(f,0,1)$value,col="tomato",lty=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use following steps

lets we want to generate $m$ samples to use in Monte-Carlo estimator

**1)** Generate $m$ sample from following distribution (with replacement )

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
 k   & 1   &  2  &  \cdots  &  n     \\ \hline
probability    &  \frac{\lambda_1}{\sum \lambda_i}  &  \frac{\lambda_2}{\sum \lambda_i}  &   \cdots  &   \frac{\lambda_n}{\sum \lambda_i}    \\
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}

and save it(in vector named $K$,In standard notation  $\sum \lambda_i=1$ So you can just ignore $\sum \lambda_i$).

**2)** Now for each $K=k$ generate sample from $\mathbb P_k(x)$

lets do it with a simple example

$X\sim .2 Normal(0,1)+.8 Normal(5,1)$

lets we want to estimate $E(X)$ (that exact value is $4$ and estimate should be near $4$). I do it in R software.

```
  > m<-100000
  > k.vector<-sample(1:2,size=m,p=c(.2,.8)/sum(c(.2,.8)),replace=T)
  > l1<-length(which(k.vector==1))
  > l2<-m-l1
  > random.g<-c(rnorm(l1,0,1),rnorm(l2,5,1))
  > mean(random.g)
  [1] 4.003443
```

This algorithm is a simple method  based on conditional porbability

$$f_X(x)=\sum \mathbb P(X=x|K=k) P(K=k)$$
 so in first step we produce one $k$ and then generate one $x$ form $\mathbb P(X|K=k)=\mathbb P_k(x)$. Next use this generated sample to estimate what you want.

Comment: What I asked was vague so I edited my post.